# Question about the Texas Instruments LMH6881 programmable gain amplifier

Tags: programmable-gain-amplifier

I want to use a PGA (programmable gain amplifier). I found the [LMH6881](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6881.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1621795284237&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F) which I will be probably using.

On page 5 of the datasheet you can see that the analog input voltage range should be between 0V and VCC (which is 5V). On page 6 of the datasheet it is stated that the input common mode voltage is 2.5V (self-biased).

So why isn't it possible to apply a single-ended -2.5V signal to the analog input. If it is self-biased then it should still be in the range of 0V to 5V, right?

Comment: no, it shouldn't. Why do you think it should?

Comment: a -2.5 V signal is not in the range 0 to 5 V. This is not an opamp, it has an input impedance of 50 ohms, not the 100s of megohms you'd expect from an opamp.

Comment: and a PGA is not an opamp, so I'm fixing both your title and your tags.

Comment: @MarcusMüller because of the 2.5V self biased input. I thought it raises the voltage level of the incoming signals by 2.5V

Comment: no, it's a self-biased input; that means that AC-coupled signals are biased towards that, not that things are shifted. I mean, if all signals would be shifted to the same voltage, what would the thing then amplify?

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok thank you I got a little bit confused.

Comment: A self biassed input to mid rail (2.5 V) is likely to be two equal resistors connected to GND and VCC, with the mid point connected to the input. The signal is then expected to be connected to this through a capacitor.